# How can I load an assembly dynamically?

Tags: c#-2.0

I'm writing a Quick Watch for visual studio from scratch. 
One part of this application is responsible for visualizing predefined visual studio debugger visualizer.
For implementing this functionality I use Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers assembly.
For loading predefined visualizers assembly I use System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("Specific Path").
Then for visualizing it I use VisualizerDevelopmentHost(objectToVisualize, visualizerType) method. But when I call ShowVisualizer method of VisualizerDevelopmentHost, the following exception catches :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Visualizer asssembly' or one of its dependencies.
```

When I add reference to specified visualizer assembly statically its work.
How can I load visualizers assembly dynamically in this scenario.

Comment: When I copy visualizers assemblies into execution path, problem resolved.

Comment: I was wondering if you were able to resolve this issue. Were you able to invoke a visualizer manually? Copying the assembly worked for me only once.